# Absolute Convergence $ \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Like always. New example, and I have no idea. Calculating with Series for 2 weeks now, seeing no progress. Its fun.

I need to check for absolute convergence and convergence of this series:

$$ \sum_{n\geq1} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}$$

I don't know how I should proceed with this series. Like there is a trick or transformation everywhere, and I'm just stuck. Every time I need to solve a new example I'm stuck.

I tried Ratio Test. Came to $ \sqrt[3]{\frac{n+2}{n+3}} $ but what should i do next? Don't know how to proceed here.

Then I tried to found a greater or smaller sequence to maybe compare them. But really every time - I'm having no clue. How do i learn this stuff?

Comment: now i tried to compare it with lower sequences like $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} \geq \frac{1}{n+2} $ where the last one is the harmonic series which diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ and the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ does not converge. So there is no absolute convergence.

For the convergence, you may use the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

EDIT : How do I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ ?

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}} $$

Thus, $\frac{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}}$ and I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to + \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}} = 1$ which means that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+2}}\sim \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}} $$
I've factorized by the highest power of $n$ since I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to + \infty} n^{\alpha} = 0$ when $\alpha<0$.

Comment: so you always just look at higher nth? like there is a 3rd square and a ^2 - so you assume n^(2/3)?

Comment: @DominiqueLüber Sorry I don't understand your question, can you develop a little more ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you came up with $ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}} $  so I asked you if you saw this by looking at the n and all things that eventually attach them in higher meaning. like +2 doesn't but the ^(1/3) (3rd root) and ^2 does i guess. together you made ^(2/3)?

Comment: Does my edit help ?

Comment: you're taking the n out of the root - I guess thats only allowed while n is positive right?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: We know that $$\sum \frac 1{n^{2/3}}\;\;\text{diverges.}\;\;\text{ Why?}$$

Now use the limit comparison test with your series and $\sum\dfrac 1{n^{2/3}}$ to show that your series does NOT converge absolutely.

The next step is to test whether the series converges by the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Hint: it does converge, conditionally, using the criterion of the alternating series.

Comment: when I take the limit comparison approach I come to $ \frac{n^\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt[3]{n+2}} $ but then?

Comment: The limit of $\dfrac {n^{2/3}}{(n^2 + 2)^{1/3}} $ approaches 1, so the series both converge, or both diverge. Since $\sum \frac 1{n^{2/3}}$ diverges, so does your series.

Comment: and how do you see this? L'Hospital?

Comment: how do you came up with ^2/3 in the bottom? for me its ^1/3?

Comment: $$\dfrac {n^{2/3}}{(n^2 + 2)^{1/3}}\cdot \dfrac{\frac 1{n^{2/3}}}{\frac 1{n^{2/3}}} = \dfrac 1{1 + (\frac{2}{n^2})^{1/3}}\to 1$$